# I need user input to puts a date where the tokens (/) are automatically put in

Tags: java, date

Sorry in advance if this was already answered but what i need is for an user to input a date in this format AAAA/MM/DD. But when the user puts the year (4 numbers) the token(/) automatically appears not giving the user user the option to put it himself.

And the next question is how do i make the user only to input numbers without thinking in the before checks.

This in advance

Comment: show some code, we have no idea how you are doing the user input.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: " how do i make the user only to input numbers without thinking " - no worries, users will do that automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html):

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("####/##/##");
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

'#' stands for only number input

Comment: Why do you think he has a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that at least in a multiplatform standard.

More info here but I don't think it will help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Maybe there are JNI multiplatform consoles somewhere that support it.